# Retrieving results from database using values with single quotes

Tags: mysql

Please i need you guys to help me on this. I have a value in my mysql database called "Men\'s Clothings". 
Am trying trying to retrieve other values that is tied to "Men's Clothings". I don't know what is wrong with this query.

SELECT * FROM `cat_items` WHERE `sub_cat` = 'Men\'s Clothing" AND `cat_id` = '3'

`cat_items` => the name of the table
`sub_cat` => is a row in `cat_items`
`cat_id` => is a row with unique values

Comment: ... what its your error message ?

Comment: Thanks Rafael . It's not giving any error it just returns empty result sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try surrounding the string double quotes

```
  SELECT * FROM cat_items WHERE sub_cat = "Men's Clothing" AND cat_id = '3'
```

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge . The first answer you suggested gave an error while the second returned an empty set

Comment: What error? and if return an empty set  mean the query sintactically is correct .. chek if the where condition are correct  cat_id really = 3 and sub_cat really = "Men's Clothing" no other space or other char...

Answer (score 0):

why you use double quote to close Men\'s Clothing ?
try to change it to single quotes

so your query would be like this 
SELECT * FROM cat_items WHERE sub_cat = 'Men\'s Clothing' AND cat_id = '3'